# Passing list or ndarray as feature_column in DNNClassifier

Tags: tensorflow-estimator

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd


a = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
b = [11,22,33]

mydata = pd.DataFrame({'images':a,'labels':b})
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('images',shape=[1,1])]


train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x =mydata,
                                                 y=mydata['labels'],
                                                 batch_size=60,
                                                 num_epochs=1,
                                                 shuffle=True)


estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[64,32,16],
                                   feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                   n_classes=2)


estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,steps=100)
```

Error I am getting is

```
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError'>, Unable to get element as bytes.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into /tmp/tmptver1w_k/model.ckpt.

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: expected bytes, list found
```

reading through multiple stackoverflow pages and github ... it has to do something with `saving_listeners`. But not able to figure it out.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

TF Estimator expects bytes as the input for x.

Try this, it should get you past this error:

```
a = [bytes([1,1]), bytes([2,2]), bytes([3,3])]
```

Comment: It should work at least with passing this specific error that you get after "INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into /tmp/tmptver1w_k/model.ckpt."

I ended up with a different error, specifically this output:

"UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported
  [[Node: dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/images/ToFloat = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_STRING, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/images/ExpandDims)]]"